# Does the spanning tree protocol come as standard in L3 switches?

Tags: switch, spanning-tree, layer3

Online there is a lot of content mentioning the spanning tree being a l2 switch feature so I guess it comes as standard/ is a given that it available for all modern l3 switches...
(Could the answer be backed up with a reliable source for the benefit of my documentation)

EDIT: see my first comment under the first answer

Comment: Hi, that is impossible to answer as there are a myriad of switches out there.

Comment: @Sebastian - I think it is a valid question - please see my comment below

Answer (score 1):

Layer-3 switches *are* layer-2 switches, with some routing. Ports used as layer-3 ports will not use STP since it doesn't make sense to use it on a routed link, but the ports used as layer-2 switch ports will have STP. In most layer-3 switches, how a port is used (layer-2 or layer-3) can be changed by configuration. It is also possible to disable STP on many layer-2 or layer-3 switches.

As Sebastian pointed out, the are far too many switch manufacturers and models for there to be any single source to add to your documentation.

Comment: Every switch MUST implement Spanning Tree because it is the only way to stop closed loops on switching. A layer 3 switch is a switch will routing capabilities, but primarily is a switch.

Sometimes there is an option to disable it. But by default, spanning tree comes enabled.

Comment: @jcbermu, yes, on ports used as layer-2 ports, assuming STP hasn't been disabled by configuration, but I know of no single definitive source to which I can refer the OP, as requested.

Comment: There are sadly switches (usually of the lower-end almost-unmanaged variety) that disable STP by default even though they actually support it... much merriment ensues in the network team when someone builds a loop on one of those.

Comment: @RonMaupin why would you choose certain ports to be used as l2 ports and some as l3? and most importantly in what circumstances/ why would you disable the STP? The reason for my question is that I thought no-one used l2 switches anymore as they make no routing decision and everyone would have an l3 switch as standard today as they are the newer generation ones...

Comment: Normally, you would have access ports (where end-devices like PCs and printers connect) as layer-2 switch ports. You may also have layer-2 trunks to other switches. The layer-3 ports connect to routers and other layer-3 devices. Disabling STP is not a good idea, but most switches provide for this. STP is only used for layer-2 ports since it is a layer-2 protocol. Layer-3 ports route, not switch, so STP doesn't work on them. Layer-2 switching between hosts on the same network is faster than layer-3 switching between networks.